# Need to change this JQuery code to check for element existence prior to processing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#js-news').ticker({
                    speed: 0.10,
                    htmlFeed: false,
                    fadeInSpeed: 600,
                    titleText: 'DASHBOARD ALERTS',
                    direction: 'ltr',
                    displayType: 'reveal',
                    controls: false
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I would like to alter it such that it only fires if #js-news is present. In older IE V10 browsers I am getting the error: "Element does not exist in DOM", and the relevant pages do not have the js-news element. Newer browser seem to cope, but not IE7,8,9.

Thoughts on code alteration appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How is `ticker` written that id does work on non-existing elements? O_O

Comment: Which `ticker` plugin do you use? Please link it!

Comment: Assuming the widget is written correctly.

Comment: This looks like jQuery News Ticker, and if you open that js file and look at line 22, it checks that it has been passed elements.  It will log a message in the console otherwise, stating "Element does not exist in DOM!" (or alert if console is not available).

Comment: `In older IE` What's your issue???

Comment: Sorry some of the question did not show due to less than character. I am using the JQuery Ticker. I have to admit that it may not be the culprit. What is the best way to identify the missing DOM element?

Comment: Methods on `jQuery.fn` are generally expected to call `.each` internally so that they work with selections of any given size. It appears that this plugin was written poorly.

Comment: @SamJolly: The point is that you shouldn't have to identify the existence of an element in a properly written plugin. It should just fail silently. Giving an `alert()` is horrendous. Personally, I'd never use code that did something that silly.

Comment: ...it [looks like](https://github.com/rhodimus/jQuery-News-Ticker/blob/master/includes/jquery.ticker.js#L419) the plugin has a `debugMode`, which is enabled by default, but they don't put this behavior behind that flag. You may just be better off modifying the source to set `debugMode` to `false` by default, and changing `if ($(this).length == 0) {` to `if (opts.debugMode && $(this).length == 0) {`

Comment: Or do this: `if (!window.console) window.console = {log:function(){}};` just to shut it up. I definitely wouldn't check for existence first.

Comment: The interesting bit about this is that it does fail silently in the most modern browsers like IE10,IE11 and all FF and Chrome I have tested. So something quirky in IE6,7,8.... is setting this off

Comment: @SamJolly That's because of `console` on older IE i guess

Comment: Sorry what is this "console" business? I am a little new on this stuff, sorry for the basic question.

Comment: See [how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: @cookiemonster, I used your snippet and it worked, in conjunction with A.Wolff's comment. Seems a bit of a workaround, but it works. Add it as an answer and then I can mark it up. I did used it conjunction with Milind's answer..

Comment: Sure, I'll add an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, as [@Archer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023618/archer) pointed out in the comments above, this plugin is not coded properly. The idiomatic jQuery plugin will fail silently when its method is invoked on a jQuery object with no elements.

As seen from the code here, this plugin either runs the `console.log()` or an `alert()` if the `console` doesn't exist when there's no element:

```
if ($(this).length == 0) {
    if (window.console && window.console.log) {
        window.console.log('Element does not exist in DOM!');
    } else {
        alert('Element does not exist in DOM!');    
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is pretty bad. The plugin does have a `debugMode` that can be disabled, but it wouldn't help because that flag isn't used here. To modify the source, you could change the first line above:

```
if (opts.debugMode && $(this).length == 0) {
```

And then be sure to set `debugMode:false` in your settings.

--

But how this ultimately affects IE is that it doesn't have a `console` object defined when the dev tools are closed *(and never in IE6/7)*, so a simple solution would be to make sure that object is defined with a NO-OP function.

```
if (!window.console) {
    window.console = {
        log: function() {}
    };
}
```

Now it will find the `console` and invoke the empty function in IE instead of firing the `alert()`.

There are other methods on the `console` object that should probably be filled in too, but the `log()` is the most common.

---

If you're so inclined, it may not be a bad idea to file a bug report with the developer. It seems that the project hasn't been updated in the last 2 years, so I don't know if it'll help, but it couldn't hurt.

Comment: What a stunning answer. Most helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Add the condition to check the length:

```
if($('#js-news').length){
  $('#js-news').ticker({
                speed: 0.10,
                htmlFeed: false,
                fadeInSpeed: 600,
                titleText: 'DASHBOARD ALERTS',
                direction: 'ltr',
                displayType: 'reveal',
                controls: false
  });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense for me. Properly written jQuery plugin will not do anything if `this` object has no elements selected.

Comment: looks like plugin is not handling that part correctly.